# BigQuery - Issue with TABLE_DATE_RANGE() function

Tags: google-bigquery

**Background:**

I have two datasets on BigQuery.

Dataset 1 is named '12345678' with tables having the names 'ga_sessions_yyyymmdd'. For example, the table names are like ga_sessions_20140721, ga_sessions_20150413 etc.

Dataset 2 is named 'DestinationTables'. The tables names are in the format yyyymmdd. For example, 20140721, 20150413 etc.

**Problem:**

Using the TABLE_DATE_RANGE(), I ran the following query on **Dataset 1**:

```
SELECT 
  [fullVisitorId] AS [fullVisitorId]
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([12345678.ga_sessions_],TIMESTAMP('2014-07-21'),TIMESTAMP('2014-07-25'));
```

This query successfully runs.

I now run a similar query on **Dataset 2**:

```
SELECT 
  [fullVisitorId] AS [fullVisitorId]
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([DestinationTables.],TIMESTAMP('2014-07-21'),TIMESTAMP('2014-07-25'));
```

However, this errors out with the message:

> Error: Can't parse table: DestinationTables

Why is this happening? Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try giving a prefix to the tables in DestinationTables, instead of ending with a '.'. Works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for identifying a dataset and a table prefix are correct in your first example:

> [12345678.ga_sessions_]

And as explained in [the docs for this function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#tablewildcardfunctions), it will expand to cover tables (in dataset 12345678) of the format:

> ga_sessions_yyyymmdd

However, in your second example, the identifier stops with just a dot where it should continue to identify a table prefix. I think the issue is that you have no prefix and so the naked dot on the end of the string is confusing the interpreter.

You may need to change your tables to have some kind of prefix, even if it's just an underscore, so that you can properly specify the prefix when calling `TABLE_DATE_RANGE`